# Pemanent login with Android app and PHP server

Tags: php, android, security

I am developing an Android Application which should feature permanent login. Like all the twitter and facebook etc apps do.

My way to implement this, is returning an Auth Token/a Session id after the login/signup, storing it in SharedPreferences and then authenticating all subsequent server requests with it.

While it works fine, I feel like it is quite naive and there might be ways to highjack the session. And it requires the session to have no timeout, which I have been told is a bad idea.

The communication with my server is done via SSL and the server is implemented in php.

So the question is, how do other apps manage their permanent login and what can I do to improve security with my current setup?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sharedprefrence` is not the correct way for this, the process is done using similar to `SynAdapter` security in android.
 Which looks like a permanent login but **actually it is not**.

Once you are logged in, your credentials are stored in `AccountManager` for security purpose in android, whenever user requires to connect to server it uses the given credentials from `AccountManager`.

Comment: what is incorrect about using shared preference for this?

Comment: Android provides AccountManager service for uid and password, use that. Using shared preference, u need to make write and retrieve operation which is much more easy in and secure in AccountManager

Answer (score 0):

you can use account manager .
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html